# Changes pushed from local are not getting affected in AWS lambda function with AppSync API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is there any way to link an AWS lambda function to an AppSync API from local and how to push changes to that lambda function from our device? Should i always upload a zip file to lambda function whenever i have a change or modification?

Is there any better way to do it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `amplify add function` from you root directory and answering the questions asked will give a function, after completing do `amplify push` to reflect the changes in AWS console